# Why I should not write Integration Tests before unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, integration-testing, agile, continuous-delivery

Extending from the explanation of [Integration Tests](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/integration-tests-scam) By J. B. Rainsberger - I mock the behavior of the remote component in my unit tests and when I reach at the boundary of my component; I add Integration tests for the mocked behavior of the remote component. This is the time I discover subtle new behavior of the remote component which enforces me to do the code changes which I think can be avoided if I write my Integration Tests before I start implementing the specification of the behavior. Please help me by sharing your experience if you have already tried this in your continuous integration or have already gave some thoughts about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you observed, integration tests incorporated into a CI pipeline can help stabilize the development environment when multiple developers/teams work in paralel on multiple components of a project by establishing a criteria for which component changes are acceptable and which are not.

On the other hand they can be seen as obstacles to overcome when cross-component changes are necessary/desired. It's not necessarily a bad thing, it can actually encourage the involved developers/teams to cooperate and together ensure the project as a whole moves in the right direction.

So some balancing act may be required, depending on the particularities of the project and of the development activities.

Comment: I agree that it is not bad thing. I seek opinion on: very first thing we should do is write integration tests so that we can eliminate those obstacles sooner than later something to add to 'fail fast'. Particularities of the projects: using components developed by 2 remote teams and 1 local team.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, provided that the teams agree and you're able to stub the code such that the tests pass (or you use a CI making it easy to distinguish actual regressions between failures in tests that never worked before). Otherwise managing the test failures may be too costly.